# .show() method is missing from Lighting Overlay Library does nothing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-overlaylibrary

So I've got this component which seems to be reasonable use:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib">
        Hello planet!
    </lightning:overlayLibrary>
</aura:component>
```

JS controller:

```
({
    init: function (component) {
        component.find('overlayLib').show();
    }
});
```

Will cause:

`Action failed: c:TestPlayground$controller$init [component.find(...).show is not a function]`

The documentation says there is one:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/specification

Does it only appear after using `showCustomModal` method? If so, it's complete bonkers.

Comment: where do you open this component? `lightning:overlayLibrary` is supported only in Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App.

Comment: I think that close, show, and hide might actually be Spring 19 enhancements, and the documentation is from the future. I can't get any of the three to work as documented.

Comment: Using in LEX, but not in a traditional way - via URL (hence implemented interface). Other methods like showCustom... is still there.